# Differences between two large files in shell script

Tags: shell, diff, comm

File 1:

```
e4300-2076g4j
e4300-2j82b4j
e4300-43w8b4j
e4300-4cppb4j
e4300-5cppb4j
e4300-6176g4j
e4300-6hy8v4j
e4300-6v7ch4j
e4300-7062b4j
e4300-8062b4j
e4300-8ch4j4j
e4300-92w8b4j
e4300-9dh4j4j
e4300-bch4j4j
e4300-cj82b4j
e4300-cnbz94j
e4300-dpy9c4j
e4300-dz66g4j
e4300-fnp3j4j
e4300-g37dr4j
e4300-gcppb4j
e4300-gmbz94j
e4300-gnknc4j
e4300-hwnnc4j
e4300-j266v4j
e4300-jmp3j4j
e4300-jy66g4j
e4310-1jbr1q1
e4310-294d2q1
e4310-2xnn3q1
e4310-2y533q1
e4310-2z533q1
e4310-41vg2q1
e4310-42vg2q1
e4310-4fvg2q1
e4310-4gvd5q1
e4310-4rtg2q1
e4310-54vg2q1
e4310-5fvt1q1
e4310-5ytg2q1
e4310-6cwd5q1
e4310-6hwd5q1
e4310-6kvg2q1
e4310-6ttg2q1
e4310-74vg2q1
e4310-87wd5q1
e4310-8bvg2q1
e4310-8dwd5q1
e4310-8gvd5q1
e4310-8jvt1q1
e4310-9cvg2q1
e4310-9fvt1q1
e4310-b4wn3q1
e4310-brtt1q1
e4310-cfvt1q1
e4310-cpwd5q1
e4310-d4wc3q1
e4310-d6cq3q1
e4310-dcvg2q1
e4310-dcwg2q1
e4310-djjp3q1
e4310-f1pn3q1
e4310-fhvd5q1
e4310-ftpn3q1
e4310-gfvt1q1
e4310-gfwd5q1
e4310-ghvt1q1
e4310-gvpn3q1
e4310-h3vg2q1
e4310-h6k05q1
e4310-hfwd5q1
e4310-hgvd5q1
e4310-j2pn3q1
e4310-j7vg2q1
e4310-jvrt4q1
e6220-5gl2xp1
e6220-9ty3xp1
e6220-b6m3xp1
e6220-b6n1xp1
e6220-b6nzwp1
e6220-b6p4xp1
e6220-b6q5xp1
e6220-bf80xp1
e6220-bfc8xp1
e6220-bfjywp1
e6220-bfw9xp1
e6220-bmdxwp1
e6220-bmhvwp1
e6220-csw5xp1
e6220-csw6xp1
e6420-1z81fs1
e6420-38p1fs1
e6420-3z81fs1
e6420-7qdc5r1
e6420-cng1fs1
e6420-gz81fs1
op760-78wsh4j
op760-8wvsh4j
op760-9wvsh4j
op760-hwvsh4j
op780-7x6405j
op780-8x6405j
op790-3t3x55j
op790-4jmx55j
op790-4kmx55j
op790-4pww55j
op790-4vyw55j
op790-5pww55j
op790-7f2x55j
op790-7t3x55j
op790-8xyw55j
op790-9lww55j
op790-bd2x55j
op790-bnmx55j
op790-bnww55j
op790-cv3x55j
op790-dkww55j
op790-fnmx55j
op790-gpww55j
op790-hnww55j
op790-jmmx55j
```

File 2:

```
e4300-2076g4j
e4300-2j82b4j
e4300-32w8b4j
e4300-43w8b4j
e4300-4cppb4j
e4300-5cppb4j
e4300-6176g4j
e4300-6v7ch4j
e4300-7062b4j
e4300-8062b4j
e4300-8ch4j4j
e4300-92w8b4j
e4300-9dh4j4j
e4300-bch4j4j
e4300-cj82b4j
e4300-cnbz94j
e4300-d062b4j
e4300-dpy9c4j
e4300-dz66g4j
e4300-g37dr4j
e4300-gcppb4j
e4300-gmbz94j
e4300-gnknc4j
e4300-j266v4j
e4300-jy66g4j
e4310-1cjp3q1
e4310-1jbr1q1
e4310-2xnn3q1
e4310-2y533q1
e4310-2z533q1
e4310-42vg2q1
e4310-4fvg2q1
e4310-4gvd5q1
e4310-4rtg2q1
e4310-5fvt1q1
e4310-5ytg2q1
e4310-6cwd5q1
e4310-6hwd5q1
e4310-6ttg2q1
e4310-74vg2q1
e4310-8dwd5q1
e4310-8gvd5q1
e4310-8jvt1q1
e4310-9cvg2q1
e4310-9fvt1q1
e4310-b4wn3q1
e4310-b8sy4q1
e4310-bmvg2q1
e4310-c44d2q1
e4310-cfvt1q1
e4310-cpwd5q1
e4310-d4wc3q1
e4310-d6cq3q1
e4310-dcvg2q1
e4310-dcwg2q1
e4310-djjp3q1
e4310-f1pn3q1
e4310-f4vg2q1
e4310-f7st1q1
e4310-fhvd5q1
e4310-gfvt1q1
e4310-gfwd5q1
e4310-ghvt1q1
e4310-h3vg2q1
e4310-h6k05q1
e4310-hfwd5q1
e4310-j7vg2q1
e4310-jvrt4q1
e6220-5gl2xp1
e6220-9ty3xp1
e6220-b6m3xp1
e6220-b6n1xp1
e6220-b6nzwp1
e6220-b6p4xp1
e6220-b6q5xp1
e6220-bf80xp1
e6220-bfc8xp1
e6220-bfjywp1
e6220-bfw9xp1
e6220-bmhvwp1
e6220-csw5xp1
e6220-csw6xp1
e6420-1z81fs1
e6420-27p1fs1
e6420-38p1fs1
e6420-3z81fs1
e6420-7qg1fs1
e6420-8d46fs1
e6420-cng1fs1
e6420-f6p1fs1
e6420-f7p1fs1
e6420-gz81fs1
op760-78wsh4j
op760-8wvsh4j
op760-9wvsh4j
op760-hwvsh4j
op780-7x6405j
op780-8x6405j
op790-3t3x55j
op790-4jmx55j
op790-4kmx55j
op790-4pww55j
op790-4vyw55j
op790-5pww55j
op790-7f2x55j
op790-7t3x55j
op790-8xyw55j
op790-9lww55j
op790-bd2x55j
op790-bnmx55j
op790-bnww55j
op790-cv3x55j
op790-dkww55j
op790-fnmx55j
op790-gpww55j
op790-hnww55j
op790-jmmx55j
```

File 1: 121 lines
File 2: 117 lines

117 lines are common between File 1 and File2, the output have to show the different lines.

I'm trying with diff, comm and fgrep with not results.

Any help?

Comment: u tried `comm -3 file1 file2`?

Comment: First of all there is no 117 common lines. `grep -vf file1 file2 | wc -l` shows 13 strings, therefore there are less common strings. Also isn't clear what's wrong? Any errors?

Comment: finally the file was wrong. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash:

```
 comm -3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```